# Sending/Receiving E-mail with Python smtpd module

Tags: python, smtplib, smtpd

I'm trying to make a simple smtp server using the Python [smtpd](http://docs.python.org/library/smtpd.html) module. I can receive an e-mail and print it out. I try to send an e-mail back to the person who sent me the e-mail with a hello world message and I end up with an infinite loop. I try to use my own server to send the e-mail and it just interprets it as another e-mail that's been received.

How can I use this to both send and receive e-mail?

```
import smtplib, smtpd
import asyncore
import email.utils
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import threading

class SMTPReceiver(smtpd.SMTPServer):
    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        print 'Receiving message from:', peer
        print 'Message addressed from:', mailfrom
        print 'Message addressed to  :', rcpttos
        print 'Message length        :', len(data)
        print data

        def send_response():
            msg = MIMEText('Hello world!')
            msg['To'] = email.utils.formataddr(('Recipient', mailfrom))
            msg['From'] = email.utils.formataddr(('Author', 'jsternberg@example.org'))
            msg['Subject'] = ''

            print 'Connecting to mail server'
            server = smtplib.SMTP()
            server.set_debuglevel(1)
            server.connect()
            print 'Attempting to send message'
            try:
                server.sendmail('jsternberg@example.org', [mailfrom], msg.as_string())
            except Exception, ex:
                print 'Could not send mail', ex
            finally:
                server.quit()
            print 'Finished sending message'
        threading.Thread(target=send_response).start()
        return

def main():
    server = SMTPReceiver(('', 25), None)
    asyncore.loop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note: Not using a real e-mail address in the example.
Note 2: Not using this as a mail server. Just want to send/receive simple e-mails for a simple service.

Answer (score 1):

You're *not* supposed to send the message to *yourself*...

Perform a [MX lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) and send the message to the appropriate SMTP server.

Comment: Any suggestions of how to do this? I've never tried to modify an smtp daemon before.

Comment: You... don't really need to modify anything. You just use a DNS library to perform the MX lookup and then connect to that server instead.